# Route 53 subdomains and their redirects

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am having problems with my redirects. I have a bucket named example.com created in s3 which redirects to http://google.com (just an example). In route 53 I am able to point my example.com domain to example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com and that works. Now I want to redirect my www.example.com subdomain to the same example.com bucket. Is this possible or do I have to create www.example.com bucket which redirects to same page as example.com bucket?

I have tried cname and alias with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible or do I have to create www.example.com bucket which redirects to same page as example.com bucket?

Yes, you'll need to create a second bucket for the `www` version. To keep things a little simpler, you can redirect the `www.example.com` to `example.com` and let the main bucket handle the final redirect.